# Is there a way to convert this Twilio CURL to RestClient?

Tags: c#, twilio-api

I would like to know how to convert this Twilio CURL code to RestClient
I am stuck in the request.AddParamenter() I have not idea how to format it order to pass the Twilio SID,Token, From, To and Body Text Message.

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID/Messages.json \
-data-urlencode "Body=Hi there" \
-data-urlencode "From=+15017122661" \
-data-urlencode "To=+15558675310" \
-u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
```

To this:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID/Messages.json");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "bodykey=bodyval", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

This is my code now that compile 100% and after I run the code I get a response "Complete" no error message and no entry at twilio dashboard either, it does not send the text message, any idea your help will be much appreciate.

```
        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACet53f18a4734c339488c1845e619dd9g/Messages.json");        
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ACet53f18a4734c339488c1845e619dd9g:daskshdsjkahkashd90ud09as8dasjkhdsa9"));
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64authorization);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("Body", "Hello World");
        request.AddParameter("From", "+15017122661");   //- My Twilio number goes 
        request.AddParameter("To", "+15017122661");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        string ResStatus = response.ResponseStatus.ToString();  //- Complete after successfully run.
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using visual studio 2010 pro framework 4.0.

Comment: Are you really using VS 2010?!

Comment: Hi DavidG, yes I am using visual studio 2010 pro that what my friend who was teaching me how to create windows forms gave me at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a RestClient request like this.

```
    RestClient client = new RestClient("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID/Messages.json");
    client.Timeout = -1;
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"));
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.AddParameter("Body", "Hi");
    request.AddParameter("From", "+15017122661");
    request.AddParameter("To", "+ 15558675310");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Ali, when I try your code I get the following error message Unexpected character '$' when compiling on this line of code request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");

Comment: What is the meaning of the "$" in the line of code "$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN", Do I really need it just by passing the Account_SID:TOKEN will do.

Comment: Unexpected character '$' when compiling on this line of code request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");  The $ in front of the string allows string interpolation - which just means you can put variables into the string using curly brackets, but if it doesn't work then instead try this: request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64authorization);

Comment: @AlDiz meaning of this line is 

Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("HERE PUT YOUR SID FROM TWILIO:HERE PUT YOUR SECERET KEY FROM TWILIO");

Comment: @AlDiz so $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID meaning just replace whole including $ with the actual SID.

Comment: Thank you Ali Ahmad for the explanation, I've done everything accordingly and got to compile 100% but when I test it it does not send the text message and per the response status is complete, meaning that it did communicate with Twilio but SMS does not go out, I logged on to the Twilio dashboard I see no error or entry of the message. Any Idea what I am doing wrong, Thanks again.

Comment: @AlDiz for "From" number you have to buy a number on Twilio and for "To" number if you are on trial your number should be included in Verified Caller IDs you can find this option Phone Numbers => Manage => Verified Caller IDs

Comment: Hi Ali Ahamad, Yes I already have Twilio account configured and ready to go I even tested sending SMS via the Twilio dashboard and it worked it just does not works with my coding posted above. In the FROM line I use my Twilio number and in the TO line I use my mobile cell number along with my Twilio credentials, but is does not work and the odd is that I don't get any error message other than "Completed" from the response and no entry found at the twilio dashboard either. Any Idea. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @AlDiz What do you mean by "along with my Twilio credentials" in TO line just put your number like +12313312312

Comment: Ali Ahmid, what I meant by credential is the "API Account SID" and "API AUTH Tocken" provided by Twilio, I've done all like it mandates, and still does not send the SMS and as I mentioned above I do not get any error message from my code neither from Twilio. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for all your inputs, since I could not get using the RestClient to work I desired to go with Twilio method which I stuck with the error message while testing "Could not load file or assembly 'Twilio, Version=5.54.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)"